# How to create/script complex speech shortcuts? (in vista)

Tags: windows, automation, windows-vista, speech

has MS Vista hooks to create something like this?

- "I have an idea" => popup my preferred idea manager
- "commit $1" => open the commit window of subversion for project $1

for hot keys there is a great API from Microsoft. But I want to do such things with the speech API.

Can I do this with scripts/config/program?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Windows Speech Recognition Macros are a great way to do exactly this. They let you write small scripts that respond to given commands. Hope this helps.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?FamilyID=fad62198-220c-4717-b044-829ae4f7c125&displaylang=en

For some examples of Macros:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wsrmacros/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1453

There's also an ms-speech yahoo group that often discusses various macros:
http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/ms-speech/